# I cant see data from the jquery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I wanted to perform jquery post to php and get the data and post to the console log. But however i cant find data on the console.log after performing post the data. my code is found below...........please help me...

student html page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NEW AJAX GET</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Cesium-1.34/ThirdParty/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
showData();
function showData()
{
    $.post("student.php",
    {
        PostLastName: "Abdullah",
        PostLastReligion: "Muslim"
    },
    function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

student.php script

```
<?php 
 if ((empty($_POST["PostLastName"])) && (empty($_POST["PostLastReligion"])))
    {
        //Return "Posted Values are empty" if the values is empty
        $post_string = 'Posted Values Are Empty';
        //echo "<script>console.log(".$post_string.");</script>";
        echo $post_string;
    }
    else
    {
        //Return the Post Data
        $post_string= 'Post Last Name = '.$_POST["PostLastName"]."\n".' Post Last Religion = '.$_POST["PostLastReligion"].'';
        //echo "<script>console.log(".$post_string.");</script>";
        echo $post_string;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the request is successful? If you check the console, are there any errors after the request is made?

Comment: the errors is empty. it is totally blank

Comment: In that case either your AJAX request is not being made at all, or you're not reading the console correctly.

Comment: oh wait i have errors the error states Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: There's your problem then - although it appears you just edited the question to fix it. Are you still having problems now?

Comment: Add your code inside $(document).ready(function(){ showdata();}); make sure document is ready or loaded before firing your function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thank for reminding me.. I am so damn careless... Careless is my worst habit..

Comment: Can you check if the call is successful? You could do this by checking the network tab:
[![network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npr5H.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npr5H.png)

Comment: oh so network tab can help to check the traffic.. Thank a lot for critical help..

Comment: only trying to help. You said you can't see the data inside your log. With the network tab you can atleast check if either your call is incorrect and you need to adjust it or that something goes wrong when you try to fetch the data inside the log.

Comment: so this could be useful in troubleshooting problems...nice

Comment: Well if you ever wanne solve your own problems when programming information gathering is key so troubleshouting will be the way to go. Anyway hope it wasn't to useless information, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have test your code. i think check first check your loaded jquery included in header.
After change some code like below mention and test your browser console.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>NEW AJAX GET</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
showData();
function showData()
{
    $.post( "student.php", { PostLastName: "Abdullah", PostLastReligion: "Muslim" })
      .done(function( data ) {
         console.log(data);
    });
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope u resolve u r issue.

[image]

Comment: Just check data post in php file and after check data in php file return status .in console js